# Flutter Dart HTTP headers not working. Sending Request with "headers". On response authorization error, {"CODE":401,"MESSAGE":"Unauthorized"}

Tags: http, flutter, http-headers

Sending request to API with authorization and other headers, its returning unauthorized. it seems like server is not getting headers while requesting. i tried different approaches to send http headers on request but failed. I tried Dio , HttpClient, Normal http request all are failed. I spent my 2 days on this thing, still not resolved. from Postman, and other mediums request is working.

```
Map<String,String> reqHeaders = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  "Authorization": "xxxxx",
  "langapi": "en"
};
Future<MzResponseData> getHttp() async {
  var dio = Dio();
  dio.options.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  dio.options.headers = reqHeaders;
  dio.options.contentType = ContentType.parse("application/json");
  Response response = await dio.get("/uri/");
  print(response);
}
```

Comment: try with Postman with the same authentication. I think the error is coming also on postman

Comment: I tried to send request with authentication headers on postman also, there its working fine. but on dart its giving error of authentication. it seems like  header is not attaching while requesting on dart .

Comment: okay. what type of authentication?

Comment: Authorization:xxxxx

Comment: no bro I mean authentication type in postman.(Bearer token or OAuth 1.0 or OAuth 2.0...)

Comment: I am using a custom header like {"Authorization" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195261/discussion-between-syed-shah-and-user9139407).

Comment: @syedshah Have you solve this? Please how did you solve it, Am having the same problem, Have searched and I don't see any solution

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
final response = await dio.get(
      url,
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<MzResponseData> getHttp() async {
  var dio = await Dio();
  dio.options.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    dio.options.headers = Options(headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'})//add your type of authentication
  dio.options.contentType = ContentType.parse("application/json");
  Response response = await dio.get("/uri/");
  print(response);
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but its giving error on line"Options(headers: {'Authorization'".ERROR: A value of type 'Options' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: dio.options.headers.addAll(reqHeaders); i tried this... but still not working